# Page routing not exactly how I intended

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have following code below where I used Angular Routing to direct users to new registration forms. The app works like this. The user sees a webpage which asks them to make a choice between a "digital quote" or "screen quote" by clicking the appropriate button. Once the button is clicked it should direct it to another page which shows the appropriate registration form. In terms of the different registration forms, I have that all built. But I have one big problem in terms of functionality. When the user clicks the button it should load the registration in a different page. I am not sure how to do that. Right not I am using an ng-view directive which means that the buttons and the initial questions still remain. My objective is that once you click the button, all you see are the corresponding/different registration pages. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. I don't believe Angular can solve this. 
Thank you
the main page-> index.html

```
<html ng-app="myHome">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/redirect.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script><!--This is to call Angular JS-->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/redirect.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="rotate">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <img src="/css/Logo_75.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <h1>WHAT TYPE OF QUOTE ARE YOU REQUESTING:</h1><br>
                <h1>DIGITAL OR SCREEN QUOTE?</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="#/digital">DIGITAL QUOTE</a></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="#/screen">SCREEN QUOTE</a></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="container">
         <div ng-view></div>
       </div>
    </body>
```

The angular JS file or the redirect.js file looks like this:

```
    var app = angular.module('myHome', [ngRoute]); 
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) { 

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: '/index.html' })
        .when('/digital', { templateUrl: '/digital.html' })
        .when('/screen', { templateUrl: '/screen.html' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }); 
}]);
```

where digital.html is the registration form for the digital option and screen.html is the screen registration form option. If anyone wants to see those registration forms, I can paste those files as well. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: what do you mean by different page? New tab? If so then set attribute `target="_blank"` on your link. This will open the page in different tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the user clicks the button it should load the registration in a
>   different page

Probably you can solve it in the next way.

Just get on button click new page from server.(remove # from href="#/digital") and create new route(/digital) in your server side application.

Comment: Hello Pomah,Thank you for your response. Is there anyway you can provide some sample code as to how I would do that? I forgot to mention that I am a front end developer and have no experience with backend programming. I was suspecting that Inwould have to use node for this sort of objective. Thanks once again for your help

Comment: if you write me here(romazzz85zzz2001@gmail.com we can discuss it  with  more details)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to use anchor tag with target="blank". Angular is total SPA, so it will (ng-view) will never allow you to open the page in a new window (which I think you trying to do). It is better you use the `<a>` tag for your current need.